# How does a spaceship respond to a centrifuge?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, torque

If you are in a spaceship and you spin a balanced centrifuge with a rock in it, does the spaceship rotate in the opposite direction as the centrifuge with the same angular, kinetic energy as the centrifuge?

Guess 1: the energy of the rotating centrifuge 50% is equal to the energy of the rotating spaceship 50%: equal torques create equal energy.

If the centrifuge releases the rock while spinning, and the rock flies off and hits the wall of the spaceship, does the spaceship obtain linear velocity from stopping the rock?

Guess 2: the energy of the rotating centrifuge is split in half between the rock 25% total and the ballast 25% total. The ballast behaves like a frictionally dampened oscillator with its half of the kinetic energy, while the rock gives the other half of kinetic energy to the spaceship as linear energy when it collides with the wall.

Guess 3: in order to have a force equal and opposite to the force of the rock hitting the wall 25%, the energy in the dampened oscillator motion of the centrifuge ballast 25% must be converted into a linear force through some means that I am unaware of or else the energy must exceed 100% of the energy applied to the centrifuge.

Guess 4: after impact, if we slow the ballast 25% in the empty centrifuge to zero, the spaceship 50% should still be rotating with 25% energy because the angular kinetic energy in the rock 25% was unavailable to slow the rotation of the spacecraft as it had been used up in the collision.

Guess 5: The translational energy of the rock 25% now belongs to the spaceship, and the rotational energy of the spaceship is also 25% which is a a net drift and a net rotation that balance each other. 50% is heat.

Question: what kinetic energies are my guesses missing in order to prove the conservation of angular and linear momentum?

Comment: There are so many similar questions answered on this site, why not look them up? Also, your problem is not helpfully informed by having rock and ballasts. Why not consider a simple centrifuge toy that only has balanced arms so that there is no complications from independently movable parts that will only serve to complicate without making the problem any more general than the toy could already fully explain? Finally, your answer must have a sensible distribution of angular momentum, momentum and energy, all conserved, and not just randomly assume their percentages.

Comment: all percentages are in total energy.

Comment: Those percentages cannot be correct. It is incredibly unlikely that the spaceship will weigh about as much as the rock, and we are not given what they are anyway.

Comment: where did you get that idea from?

Answer (score 1):

> If you are in a spaceship and you spin a balanced centrifuge with a rock in it, does the spaceship rotate in the opposite direction as the centrifuge with the same angular, kinetic energy as the centrifuge?

Almost. You spin in the opposite direction with equal (magnitude) angular momentum. Since the spaceship presumably has a much higher moment of inertia, this will be a quite low angular velocity. This is required by the conservation of angular momentum.

The kinetic energy will be partitioned in whatever manner is required for the angular momentum to be conserved. Kinetic energy is not a conserved quantity, only total energy. So consideration of kinetic energy is not useful for this question.

> If the centrifuge releases the rock while spinning, and the rock flies off and hits the wall of the spaceship, does the spaceship obtain linear velocity from stopping the rock?

Yes, but it will be the equal and opposite linear velocity that it just gained upon releasing the rock. Releasing the rock will make it move (a rocket). And then hitting the rock will make it stop. This is required by the conservation of linear momentum.

Comment: I nearly flagged your answer---Dale answering Dale...

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Haha, yes, I noticed that too. Oh well, it is not a particularly unique name

Comment: If there is an equal and opposite linear velocity gained upon release of the rock, what causes this equal and opposite velocity? please be specific.

Comment: @Dale, It's from the force of the centrifuge.  If it flung a rock, it do so by applying a force.  There is therefore an equal and opposite force on the centrifuge.  If it is fixed to the spaceship, then the force is also applied to the spaceship.  This is just Newton's 3rd, same as a gun firing a bullet.

Comment: @BowlofRed If a rock is released from the centrifuge like a rock from a sling, there is no force.

Comment: At the very last moment of release, the force becomes zero.  But the centrifuge certainly applied a force to the rock before the release.  *That* is the force that must be countered.

Comment: @BowlOfRed That is know as torque, which I accounted for through the rotation of the spacecraft countering the rotation of the centrifuge.

Comment: @Dale BowlOfRed is correct. The torque and the force both exist. Accounting for the torque does not get rid of the force

Comment: @Dale Force times lever arm distance = torque, is this what you are referring to? Please describe the force in detail. Saying there is a force is very vague.

Comment: @Dale it is the force from the centrifuge. I don’t know what more detail you need or what you think is vague. The centrifuge exerts a force on the rock to make it orbit around in a circle. It is that force, or rather the 3rd law reaction force from the rock back on the centrifuge. This is the force that makes an unbalanced centrifuge shake

Comment: @Dale The centripetal force on the rock is equal and opposite to the centripetal force on the ballast. This force can only accelerate the spaceship to make it shake like an unbalanced centrifuge after the rock is released. The centripetal force is unable to make the spacecraft accelerate linearly, which is what you said is happening to counteract the released rock.

Comment: The centripetal force *is* able to make the spacecraft accelerate linearly if it is not constant.  By releasing the rock, the force was stronger in one direction than the other and you get a net acceleration (both of the rock and the centrifuge due to 3rd law).    If that was not true, the rock could not fly away.

Comment: Also, the centrifuge does not apply *only* centripetal forces.  At constant speed it does, but during the spin-up process, some component of the force is non-centripetal.

Comment: @Dale the ballast doesn’t change anything. I treat it as part of the ship, just like any other moving parts or people aboard. It doesn’t matter if the rock shakes the ship by shaking a small part of the ship (the ballast) a lot or by shaking the whole ship a little. Either way the change in momentum is the same

Answer (score 0):

> does the spaceship rotate in the opposite direction as the centrifuge with the same angular, kinetic energy as the centrifuge?

You always conserve momentum.  You do not have to conserve energy.  When a bullet is fired from a rifle, the bullet and the rifle will instantaneously have opposite momenta.  They will not have similar kinetic energies.

*Something* has to have opposite momentum, but it doesn't have to be the entire spaceship.  As an example, you could have 2 centrifuges on a table.  But if they spin in opposite directions, then the ship would remain fixed.  Or you could have one centrifuge on a table, but the table is not connected to the ship.  The centrifuge would spin one way, and the table the other.

Are you only interested in the case where the centrifuge is firmly attached to the ship?

> If the centrifuge releases the rock while spinning, and the rock flies off and hits the wall of the spaceship, does the spaceship obtain linear velocity from stopping the rock?

Yes, but it also gets linear velocity from when the rock was released.  The two will be equal and opposite (assuming the rock stops when it reaches the wall).

Mechanical energy is lost in the collision, but momentum is conserved.

Comment: How does releasing a rock from a centrifuge cause an equal and opposite force?

Comment: All forces are created in equal and opposite pairs.  The force the centrifuge places on the rock has an opposite force from the rock to the centrifuge.  Moving the rock from one side of the centrifuge to the other creates forces that accelerate the rock (and accelerate the spaceship).